# Defining a class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, model

I am trying to make a model class in Node.js and am having some trouble.

---

## Code:

> MosaicStreamer.js

This is how I'm trying to define the class.

```
function MosaicStreamer() {
    
}

module.exports = MosaicStreamer;
```

> App.js

```
app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    'use strict'; 
    var models = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js'); 
    var mosaic_streamer = new MosaicStreamer; 
    res.render('view', {type: "block", name: "Sara", latitude: "", longitude: "", zoom: ""}); 
});
```

Here I am trying to create an instance of the `MosaicStreamer` class.

---

## Error:

I keep getting:

> ReferenceError: MosaicStreamer is not defined

The stack trace points to `var mosaic_streamer = new MosaicStreamer;` in `app.js`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are assigning `MosaicStreamer` to `models`, which means the Object (not class) is held by that variable. You'll have to call the `new` keyword on that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function and variable has to be defined in each file separatly.

Simply replace

```
var models = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js');
```

with

```
var MosaicStreamer = require('./models/MosaicStreamer.js');
```

to assign the exported named function `MosaicStreamer` (class) to your local variable `MosaicStreamer` instead of `models`